# How to create an EC2 instance that others can import into their own VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS. I am trying to put my application on AWS. I envision to have two EC2 instances.

My goal is to provide a link to the AWS instance to my users so that they can "import" the instances created by me into their own VPC. By doing so I am planning to save users the pain for setting up my application.

Is this possible to do with AWS? Where should I begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an image of your running AMI and then share it as a "public" AMI.

You can create an image by selecting the running EC2 instance in the console and then under the "Actions" dropdown select "Image" and then "Create Image".

Once your image is created you can modify the permissions using the method outlined in the following docs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-intro.html

If you wish to distribute you AMI through the AWS Marketplace there are some hoops that you need to jump through and forms to submit to get your product metadata into the marketplace.

Start by creating an account here:
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/management/tour/

Comment: Yes, they must be shared with the AWS marketplace account.  Check the documentation here under "AMI Sharing with AWS Marketplace": https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/help/200940360

Comment: Thanks! Info you provided will get me started on this. As a separate note, What would you recommend is a good way to get up to speed with AWS for someone who has a little bit of knowledge of what cloud is and does.

Comment: Look around in the console and see what options are available, then search the docs when you have questions.  The docs are sometimes not as helpful when you have a specific situation.  That is when you can search the forums.  The AWS forums have a wealth of information in them.